# Building a regular grammar from NFA

Tags: regular-language, context-free-grammar

I'm requested to make a regular grammar from a given NFA.
In this NFA, there's a "death state", which means, when getting to it, there's no way back to the rest of the states (a self-loop to the same state given any letter).

How would I translate that in my grammar?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It won’t translate directly: you’re grammar simply won’t generate strings that would put the NFA in the death state. (I’ve always called it the *garbage state*, myself.)

Comment: so just ignore this state and the transitions to it when I make the grammar?

Comment: If you’re using some algorithm to do the translation, it should have a provision for dealing with such a state. If not, you’ll have to take into account the *effect* of the death state; it just won’t correspond to any actual entity in the grammar.

Comment: I’ll make a short answer out of it; it’ll take just a minute. (And I’ll get rid of the bloomin’ misspelling!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won’t translate directly: your grammar simply won’t generate strings that would put the NFA into the death state (a much more dramatic term than my *garbage state*). If you’re using some algorithm to do the translation, it should have a provision for dealing with such a state. If not, you’ll you’ll have to take into account the *effect* of the death state, but it won’t correspond to any actual entity in the grammar.